# Spring boot "unique=true" not working after server restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to setup an application with JPA entity.
I am seeing following behavior.

I have an JPA entity "users" as below:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
private UUID userId;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
private String username;

@NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
private String password;
...
```

I have added the constraint on column `username` since I would like to avoid duplicate usernames. I can see this constraint definition in database table.

I also have a dummy data loader component which saves the mock user on application restart -

```
@Component
@Profile(ServiceConstants.PROFILE_LOCAL)
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        prefix = "vault.service.mock_data_loader",
        name = "enabled",
        havingValue = "true"
) // default is false
public class MockDataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Override
public void run(final ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    log.info("Loading mock data...");
    loadMockUser();
}

 private void loadMockUser() {
    final User user1 = User.builder()
                           .username("admin")
                           .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                           .enabled(true)
                           .fullName("Admin One")
                           .email("email")
                           .build();
    final User savedUser = userRepository.save(user1);
}
}
```

My understanding was that if I put the constraints on a column, I should not be able to add the same user again(because the username will be the same). This works fine when I am adding users without restarting the server i.e. in the same session.

However, each time I restart my server and this mock data loader runs, it updates existing(or inserts new) record in the db(I see UUID changes).

If I add 2 users(with same username) in the above method, I can see that exception is thrown.

I have following configuration in my `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

`unique = true` means that if JPA creates the database, then the column would have a unique constraint. It does nothing in pre-existing tables and columns, and it also doesn't stop you from trying to insert duplicate values. So if the column already existed without the unique constraint, you will be able to insert duplicate values, and if the column was created by JPA or if it actually has an unique constraint, you'll still be able to attempt to insert a duplicate value, resulting in an exception.

Comment: I deleted all the tables and let JPA create the tables. I can see the constraint was added in the table definition.